# SubString match in Google Sheets using Regex and Query

Tags: regex, google-sheets

This is the data in google sheets

```
Account Numkber             Names
7728550,543216              Govt Req
772855,65432                Vodafone
```

I am trying to do a lookup of the account numbers with the formula

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!B$3:C$4,"Select C where B matches '^.*(" & B2 & ").*$' limit 1")
```

772855 - Govt req

How do I solve this ? There is a large chunk of data so I can't paste the values in different rows.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(Sheet1!F2:F, ",")&"×"&Sheet1!G2:G), "×"), 2, )))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with my query is that it's doing a partial match and giving output of Govt req fr the 772855 , which should have been vodafone.

Comment: @TechieNerd can you share a copy of your sheet?